# The ref_count of this smart pointer needs to be heap allocated?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

[image]

I was taking a look at the smart pointer implementation from a book ([cracking the code interview](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/145157827X)) which reads like the following:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class SmartPointer
{

protected:
    T* ref;
    unsigned int* ref_count;

public:
    SmartPointer(T* ptr)
    {
        ref = ptr;
        ref_count = (unsigned*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
        *ref_count = 1;
    }

    SmartPointer(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        ref = sptr.ref;
        ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
        ++*ref_count;
    }

    SmartPointer<T> & operator=(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        if (this != &sptr)
        {
            ref = sptr.ref;
            ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
            ++*ref_count;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~SmartPointer()
    {
        --*ref_count;
        if (!ref_count)
        {
            delete ref;
            free(ref_count);
            ref = NULL;
            ref_count = NULL;           
        }
    }
};

class Car
{

};

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<Car> car = new Car;
}
```

Since this came from a section about C++:

Question 1) Wouldn't it make more sense to have the following?

```
ref_count = new unsigned int ; // instead of ref_count = (unsigned*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));

delete ref_count; // instead of free(ref_count);
```

Question 2) Or to have `ref_count` on the stack like in the following?

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> 
class SmartPointer
{

protected:
    T* ref;
    unsigned int ref_count;

public:
    SmartPointer(T* ptr)
    {
        ref = ptr;
        // ref_count = new unsigned int ; // ref_count = (unsigned*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned));
        ref_count = 1;
    }

    SmartPointer(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        ref = sptr.ref;
        ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
        ++ref_count;
    }

    SmartPointer<T> & operator=(SmartPointer<T>& sptr)
    {
        if (this != &sptr)
        {
            ref = sptr.ref;
            ref_count = sptr.ref_count;
            ++ref_count;
        }
        return *this;
    }

    ~SmartPointer()
    {
        --ref_count;
        if (!ref_count)
        {
            delete ref;
            // delete ref_count; // free(ref_count);
            ref = NULL;
            // ref_count = NULL;            
        }
    }
};

class Car
{

};

int main()
{
    SmartPointer<Car> car = new Car;
}
```

Question 3) There are many types of smart pointers (https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers), implementation above looks like a unique_prt, shared_ptr or perhaps a weak_ptr?

Appreciate if you recommend a smart pointer implementation I should take a look.

Comment: I presume the intent was that a `SmartPointer` could be copied and then the copy would share the same `ref_count`, but then they never bother attempting to increment it upon copy, nor ensuring it's thread-safe, and of course the use of `malloc` and such is out of place in C++, etc., etc. - basically this just looks like poor code. The real answer is: just use `std::shared_ptr`, and trust stdlib implementors to write good code, not stuff like this.

Comment: There was more in the book, I updated the question including another ctor and assigment operator.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which book?

Comment: Updated question to name the book.

Comment: For the newly added question 3: It's a broken version (as pointed out in the first comment) of a `shared_ptr`. Though you should avoid adding new questions via an edit, as it may invalidate existing answers

Answer (score 2):

> Question 1) Wouldn't it make more sense to [use new instead of malloc]?

Sure. Only reason to need `malloc` in C++ is to use a poorly designed C API that requires it. There is no need to use it here.

> Question 2) Or to have ref_count on the stack like in the following?

Think about how destruction of one pointer could affect all other refcounts stored somewhere else. It would not work.

Answer (score 1):

> Question 1) Wouldn't it make more sense to have the following?

Since `unsigned` is [default initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization) (in short, no initialization action at all!), so by using `new`/`delete` you're just using another pair of allocator/deallocator. Of course this would make your code more C++.

> Question 2) Or to have ref_count on the stack like in the following?

Stack-like allocating reference counter is not possible. You may give it a try, and you will figure out why not possible, on yourself.